# Laravel cron not working automatically

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-artisan

I'm working on a project in Laravel through scotch box. I am trying to automate some things through cronjobs. The problem is that my cron does not run automatticly, but when I `php artisan schedule:run` it runs my task perfectly.

**app/commands/sendmail.php**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Mail;

 class sendmail extends Command {
  protected $name = 'sendMail';
  protected $description = 'A mail has been send ';

public function fire()
{
    Mail::send([],[], function($message)  {
       //sendmail function that works...
    });    
    }
 }
```

**app/console/Kernel.php**

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Battle;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Console\Commands\Inspire;
use App\Commands\mails;
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    \App\Console\Commands\sendmail::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->everyMinute();

    $schedule->command('sendMail')
        ->everyMinute();
}
}
```

**crontab -e**

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * php var/www/artisan schedule:run
```

Comment: Oke! But what is the difference?

Comment: Okey, No problem. Still not working though

Comment: Try adding a slash at the start of the path `/var/www/artisan`

Comment: Wauw, okey that did it... Thanks!

Comment: without the slash in front of /var/www/artisan (like @NicklasKevinFrank said) you're running artisan in the wrong relative folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being the use of an relative path versus absolute path.

Using the relative path defined as `var/www/artisan` will set the path according to present working directory. That would mean `App/Console/var/www/artisan` where no artisan was located.

Instead using an absolute path such as `/var/www/artisan` will set the directory directly to `/var/www/artisan`, which would be the correct location of artisan.

Answer (score 1):

`* * * * * php -d register_argc_argv=On /var/www/artisan schedule:run`